# Find duplicates of two column combination

Tags: google-sheets

Let I have two column, **A** and **B** . How I can find duplicates of this two column combination?
[image]

As shown in the picture, duplicate of combination of two column will be colored.

Comment: The menu has Data-->Sort Range. http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/16.2

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to sort, the result should look like as the image showing. The formula should only color the desired row like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the duplicates highlighted, with the help of following script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name : "Check Duplicates",functionName : "duplicates"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};

function duplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = s.getRange("A:B");
  var v = r.getValues();
  r.setBackground('white');
  var f = r.getBackgrounds();
  var lastrow = getLastPopulatedRow(v);

  for( var i=0;i<lastrow;i++){
    for( var j=i+1;j<lastrow;j++){
      if( ( v[i][0]==v[j][0] && v[i][1]==v[j][1] ) || ( v[i][0]==v[j][1] && v[i][1]==v[j][0] ) ) {
        f[i][0]='lightgreen';
        f[i][1]='lightgreen';
        f[j][0]='lightgreen';
        f[j][1]='lightgreen';
      }
    }
  }
  r.setBackgrounds(f);
};

function getLastPopulatedRow(data) {
  for (var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    for (var j=0;j<data[0].length;j++)
      if (data[i][j]) return i+1;
  return 0;
};
```

Run the function "duplicates" from the script editor. You will also be able to run it from the custom menu "Scripts" from your spreadsheet.

[Here is the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxZfj.png)

Comment: I'm finding this error: **"TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 10, file "")"**

Comment: Yeah! its working, I have to just change this `var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');` line with my appropriate Sheet name instead of "Sheet1".

Answer (score 3):

Use the following *Custom formula* for *Conditional formatting*:

```
=countif(arrayformula($A:$A&"|"&$B:$B);$A1&"|"&$B1)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @jwilson gave the proper answer.
However, here is a shortcut method, it may help you.

Select a cell and use `CONCATENATE` function to join two column value with a `space` between them. Then you can search the current column if they have duplicates.
For example, using your example image, select your column **C1** and add `=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)` and drag this to applicable the formula for all cells in column **C**. Then add a conditional format rules for column **C** to check duplicates using `=countif(C:C,C1)>1`.
Here what is happening is, value of column **A** and **B** is concatenating first, then compared if those have duplicate entry in the record.